# How to exclude certain properties from binding in ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

How do I exclude certain properties, or explicitly specify which model properties should be bound by Web Api model binder? Something similar to `CreateProduct([Bind(Include = "Name,Category") Product product)` in ASP.NET MVC, without creating yet another model class and then duplicating all the validation attributes for it from the original model.

```
// EF entity model class
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }       // Exclude
    public string Name { get; set; }  // Include
    public string Email { get; set; } // Include
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; } // Include for Admins only
}

// HTTP POST: /api/users | Bind Name and Email properties only
public HttpResponseMessage Post(User user)
{
    if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(this.ModelState);
    }

    this.db.Users.Add(user);
    this.db.SaveChanges();
    return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK));
}

// HTTP POST: /api/admin/users | Bind Name, Email and IsAdmin properties only
public HttpResponseMessage Post(User user)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(this.ModelState);
    }

    this.db.Users.Add(user);
    this.db.SaveChanges();
    return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JSON, you can use the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to decorate your model properties.

```
public class Product
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Id { get; set; }          // Should be excluded
    public string Name { get; set; }     // Should be included
    public string Category { get; set; } // Should be included
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Downloads { get; set; }   // Should be excluded
}
```

For XML, you can use the DataContract and DataMember attributes.

More info about both at the [asp.net website](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization).

Comment: This way I won't be able to specify inclusion/exclusion list per action method. For example, there could be a different set of properties to include for the same model which is used in different action methods.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but maybe creating your own ModelBinder by implementing IModelBinder may get you to your solution.  That way you can create an attribute similar to what `Bind` does and attach it to the paramater for your action. [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Exclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.server.excludeattribute%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) attribute.

So now your class look something like this -

```
public class Product
{
    [Exclude]
    public int Id { get; set; }          // Should be excluded
    public string Name { get; set; }     // Should be included
    public string Category { get; set; } // Should be included
    [Exclude]
    public int Downloads { get; set; }   // Should be excluded
}
```

Comment: This is specific to WCF